# Apache ProxyPass: Page not refreshing automatically after SSL installed

Tags: apache, ssl, ansible, certbot

yesterday I configured an Apache Reverse Proxy to get a SSL certificate for Ansible AWX inside a docker running on port 8080. Apache with the proxy is in front of the docker listening on port 80.
Everything's working fine but now if I'm starting a job the site is not refreshing itself. I have to do it manually to get results. If I'm doing it through browsing server ip it's working fine.

This is the code of my default.conf:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin mail@example.com

ProxyPass / http://IP:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://IP:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


Redirect permanent / https://example.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPass / ws://IP:8080/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} 
[END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you inspect your browser's developer console for any errors (during expected refresh)?

Comment: Good point, thank you. Getting a WebSocket error:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/websocket/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Comment: then https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks - it works! Just added this to my default.conf

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint, Dusan. It's solved.

It was a websocket error and I fixed it with adding those lines of code into my default.conf.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```